# Connecting to a webservice using sockets in Java 1.3

Tags: java, web-services, sockets

I've googled around trying to find an easy answer to this question but couldn't find one. First off, I came from a .NET background and even though I had a little experience with Java, things are proving to be quite messy. I've already accomplished this connection using Eclipse Ganymede's capabilites of creating a webservice client, but it relies on rmi and unfortunatelly, it is not an option to me as I'm working with a very limited subset of JDK 1.3. I'm trying to consume a .NET webservice (asmx) in a Java client and my options are both ksoap2 or sockets. I kinda accomplished that with ksoap2, but couldn't deploy the application in the target machine (a Ricoh MFP). Any pointers or good tutorials on how to do it?

Comment: So what was the issue in trying to deploy? JDK 1.3 is really old!!!

Answer (score 0):

None of the current SOAP stacks will work with 1.3 (heck except for JAX-RPC which I think requires 1.4). You'll either manually write your own stack or use a new JDK. I mean you MIGHT be able to find an old Apache Axis version that supports 1.3 - I think they used to. But you really really want to update your java version if possible. 1.3 is very obsolete.